# Service broker error for Workload Scheduler

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, workload-scheduler

I'm using Liberty Buildpack for Java on the internal IBM Cloud instance. When I'm trying to add Workload Scheduler as a service to my Integration app - I'm facing this error

> Service broker error: {"description"=>"AWSSAS010E No object was found of type \"Environment\"."}

Without Scheduler - the project will be useless. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please put the contents of the image in your question. Do not use external links.

Comment: John, this type of image posting offered by StackOverflow via imgur. If you know the other option - I would like to know it

Comment: If you use a picture, search does not work for your question. Solution. Type the text into your question. There are cases where an image is required, this is not one of them.